# Files auditor doesn't get the name of the user who is logged-in

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

We are using IO.FileSystemWatcher watcher for test purposes on our QA machine running W2012.

- The Powershell script runs as schedule task every time a new user do a login in the machine.
- The Powershell script will capture on a log file and send emails on every change (create, rename, delete, change).
- The SystemFileMonitor Powershell script works well, with exception that is not capturing the name of the user who made the change; instead it always captures the name of the user who is running the Schedule Task.

Do you have any idea?

I even tried capture a service owner, but I still have the same issue.

This is the code I am using.

```
*$location = Get-location
$machine = [Environment]::MachineName
$userLogged = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name
$userLogged1 = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter      "Name='explorer.exe'").getOwner() | Select User
$folder = "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.33\webapps"
$filter = "*.ini"

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{
IncludeSubdirectories = $false NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName,     LastWrite'
}

$onCreated = Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Created -SourceIdentifier FileCreated -Action{
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
$name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name
$changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
$timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

Write-Host "The file '$name' was $changeType at $timeStamp" and $userLogged and Process Owner '$userLogged1' -fore green

Out-File -FilePath $location\logs\INI-outlog-Created.txt -Append -InputObject "The file '$name' was '$changeType' at '$timeStamp' on machine '$machine' on Path:'$path' , by user '$userLogged' Process Owner '$userLogged1'"

#SEND EMAIL#
$From = "test@test.com"
$To = "test1@test.com"
$Cc = "test2@test.com"
$Attachment = "$location\logs\INI-outlog-Created.txt"
$Subject = "File Created – CHANGE ALERT SERVERTRUNK"
$Body = "File Created @ SERVERTRUNK – The file '$name' was '$changeType' at '$timeStamp' on machine '$machine' on Path:'$path' , by user '$userLogged' Process Owner '$userLogged1'"
$SMTPServer = "MailServer"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Cc -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Attachments $Attachment -Priority High -dno onSuccess, onFailure}*
```

I always get this message.

> The file 'renamed – Copy.ini' was 'Deleted' at '10/03/2016 10:11:36' on machine 'TESTQA' on Path:'C:\Monitor1\Source1\renamed – Copy.ini' , by user '@{User=SVC_TEST}'

Comment: `$userlogged` is being set to the current user.  What user are you expecting instead, if not the user logged in when the script runs?  The phrase "*Username who made the change*" is vague.  You don't show how the scheduled task is triggered, but somehow you'll need to save the username at that time.

Comment: What does it say in place of `$userlogged1`?

Comment: @RyanBemrose: Thanks for your answer. yes, I'm expecting the logged user, but, if another user login on that machine and perform changes, the captured user is the one running the SC task, and not the logged in. The SC task is triggered every time when a user login, and calls the batch file: "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -file "C:\Monitor1\Full-3folders.ps1".  The issue here is that i would like the logged user to know who did the change, and not the user is running SC Task.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: The $userlogged1 wuth instructions as below is returning the user that is running the SCtask. " $userLogged1 = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'").getOwner() | Select User"

Comment: Right, but what string result does it actually yield? Your sample output doesn't show

Comment: Sorry @MathiasR.Jessen: Result of the string :$userLogged1 =  (Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='explorer.exe'").getOwner() | Select User""

**User                                                                                                                                                                                 
----                                                                                                                                                                                 
PSalvador**